# C language - Fscanf and sprint commands in unix environment

Tags: c, unix, printf, scanf

I am trying to read file with 30 rows and 5 columns with separator of "tab". Each time I get only part of the rows. 
In the windows environment it's working good. Any idea why in unix it is not working?

```
while (fscanf(FFMapFile, "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t", fnfMap[i].COS_ID, fnfMap[i].FF_First_Act, fnfMap[i].FF_Next_Act, nfMap[i].Free_FF_allowed, fnfMap[i].FF_Change_Charge) != EOF)
{ 
    sprintf(s,"%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t", nfMap[i].COS_ID, fnfMap[i].FF_First_Act, fnfMap[i].FF_Next_Act, fnfMap[i].Free_FF_allowed, fnfMap[i].FF_Change_Charge);
    error_log(s,ERROR);
    i++; }
```

Comment: can you post a sample row and tell us how much of it is read?

Comment: Are you using the exact same file. Windows/Unix tabs are interpreted differently. Chances are, a file created using tabs on windows when copied to unix may not be as expected.

Comment: @Gunner - are you sure you're not confusing tabs with end-of-line markers?

Comment: I agree. Surely `\t` for tab is universal?  Don't as said, confuse with `\n` versus `\r`n`

Comment: Whitespace in the format string, such as \t, vacuums up whitespace in the input, such as \t and \r and \n and spaces.  This program's use of \t is obscure but valid.

Comment: @detly: Actually I know that newlines differ, but not sure if tabs also differ or not. I guess they are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the return value from `fscanf()` more carefully; it will return, for example, 3 if it matches 3 fields.  You might want to be careful about the sizes of the various strings to avoid buffer overflows - that is, however, probably a subject for another day.

The possibility which strikes me is that the last tab in the format string might be better as a newline - but `fscanf()` normally takes a fairly liberal attitude towards white space in the format strings and data.

This simplified (but complete, working) version of your code behaves more or less sanely on MacOS X.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char b1[20], b2[20], b3[20], b4[20], b5[20];
    while (fscanf(stdin,"%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t", b1, b2, b3, b4, b5) == 5)
        printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", b1, b2, b3, b4, b5);
    return 0;
}
```

However, it did treat a string '`k k k k k`' (5 single letters separated by blanks) as equivalent to separated by 5 tabs.  The problem, therefore, is that section §7.19.6.2 of the C standard specifies:

> The format is composed of zero or more directives: one or more white-space
>   characters, an ordinary multibyte character (neither % nor a white-space character), or a
>   conversion specification.
>
> Input white-space characters (as specified by the isspace function) are skipped, unless
>   the specification includes a [, c, or n specifier.

Also, with regards to the '%s' specifier, it says:

> Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters.

To force matching of actual tabs, you'd have to work quite a bit harder.  It would be much easier to resort to the 'read a line into a buffer (`fgets()`) and split it manually'.  This will also allow you to enforce 5 words on a line and you can generate an error or warning if there are too few or too many fields.  With `fscanf()`, you cannot do that.  If you type 8 words on a line, it will read the first five the first time, then the remaining three words on the line plus the first two on the next, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The \t characters in your fscanf() string are not necessary - tabs are whitespaces, so you may just as well say "%s%s%s%s" - conceivably, the two scanf implementations are treating them differently. Also, you should be checking for fscanf returning a value other than EOF but not equal to the number of expected conversions, which would indicate a conversion error of some sort.

Comment: "you may just as well say "%s%s%s%s" " -- No, even when we fix your typo to "%s%s%s%s%s" (five strings instead of 4) it still won't be a substitute.  But "%s%s%s%s%s\t" to vacuum up trailing whitespace would be a substitute.

Answer (score 0):

On success, the `fscanf` returns the number of items succesfully read. 
This count can match the expected number or be less in case of a matching failure.

You should check `fscanf`s return value to see which line isn't parsed correctly and examine your input data.